# Generate QR code on page load

Tags: javascript, qr-code

So i'm trying to generate a QR code on page load so people don't have to browse through my website on their mobile to get to one page. The code I have is:

```
<script>
function process()
{
var url=" https://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?size=150x150&data==" + window.location.href;
}
</script>
<body onload="process()">
</body>
```

And i'm not too sure where i'm going wrong with this ? It would be great if someone could point out the mistake please.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be generating the QR code but you are not displaying, you need to put the image somewhere on the page -the following is only a guide

```
<script>
function process()
{
   var url=" https://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?size=150x150&data==" + window.location.href;
   document.getElementById('QRCode').src = url;
}
</script>
<body onload="process()">
   <img src='' id='QRCode' ...>
</body>
```